# Is there a term for the argument of the sine function outside of geometry?

Tags: terminology, harmonic-oscillator, geometry

Are there similar terms in other areas for the idea the "angle" conveys in geometry? I find that functions for abstract things such as pressure, electrical currents (nothing geometric there) on AC circuits and are described by the sine function (argument is an angle, therefore a geometric entity). Do we really have that abstract things are necessarily described by geometric entities?

Maybe the concept of angle we know is a simply an example of a greater idea (like a  a measure of difference between instances of the same thing) applied to geometry or am I tripping?

Answer (score 2):

The term that gets close to what you're describing is **phase** or **phase angle**. Any time you have a periodic oscillation (i.e. something which exhibits the same pattern over and over again), you can associate a phase with it, which describes at what point in the cycle it is.

It's conventional to define the phase such that a change in phase of $2\pi$ corresponds to one complete cycle. We do this because you can decompose any function $f(x)$ with a period of $2\pi$ into a sum of sines and cosines with simple arguments:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n\sin(nx) + B_n\cos(nx)$$

Note that just because something is the argument of a sine (or cosine) function doesn't mean that it actually *is* a geometric angle. The phase angle can be thought of as an angle in some abstract mathematical space whose dimensions don't correspond to our real, physical spatial dimensions.